# Exception when backing up with Casper 6.0

Tags: windows, backup

I'm using [Casper 6.0](http://www.fssdev.com/products/casper/) to create an image of my XP machine.  After upgrading from version 4.0 I started getting a strange error when doing a SmartClone of my hard drive.

> Warning: The contents of folder "\?\D:*.*" could not be accessed.
>
> Warning: The file "\?\D:\" could not be copied.

I know it's related to permissions on D:\ but I've tried giving my account Full Control and Modify access to Everyone with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to open up the Advanced Security Settings on D:\ (via the Security tab in the Properties window) and make sure the permissions for CREATOR OWNER were applied to "This folder, subfolders, and files" instead of "Subfolders and files only".

The issue was that there were other permissions set for CREATOR OWNER and possibly Users which only granted access to Subfolders and files, and not the current folder.